# Libpython2.7 build error, groovy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Having an issue building some code that worked well in fuerte. As far as I can tell, it has been modified correctly. The compilation error comes from an inability to find libpython2.7.so.

Anyone else have this problem (and perhaps a solution)?

```
allenh1@allenh1-Vostro-430:~/filter_ws/src/data_viewer$ rosmake
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['data_viewer']                    
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['data_viewer']                            
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/allenh1/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130530-100530
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['data_viewer'] to:
['data_viewer']                  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_commonComplete ]
 No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
 No Makefile in package rosclean
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
 No Makefile in package angles
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
 No Makefile in package rosparam
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                         
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                           
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
 No Makefile in package rosmaster
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> qt_build [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-6] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]                               
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< qt_build ROS_NOBUILD in package qt_build              
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-6] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib_msgs
 No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> move_base_msgs [ make ]                               
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< move_base_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package move_base_msgs  
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
 No Makefile in package rosout
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
 No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
 No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> actionlib [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                              
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< actionlib ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib
 No Makefile in package actionlib
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
 No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
 No Makefile in package tf
[rosmake-7] Starting >>> data_viewer [ make ]                                  
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesta_viewer: 13.1 sec ]      [ 1 Active 38/39 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build
  cd build && make -j8 -l8
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  [  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  Scanning dependencies of target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  [ 16%] [ 16%] [ 25%] [ 33%] Generating src/moc_ShapeAverageThread.cxx
  Generating qrc_images.cxx
  Generating src/moc_ViewerWindow.cxx
  Generating src/moc_RobotThread.cxx
  Scanning dependencies of target data_viewer
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  [ 41%] [ 50%] [ 58%] [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/data_viewer.dir/src/main.cpp.o
  [ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/data_viewer.dir/src/ShapeAverageThread.cpp.o
  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/data_viewer.dir/src/RobotThread.cpp.o
  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/data_viewer.dir/src/ViewerWindow.cpp.o
  [ 83%] [ 91%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/data_viewer.dir/qrc_images.cxx.o
  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/data_viewer.dir/src/moc_RobotThread.cxx.o
  Building CXX object CMakeFiles/data_viewer.dir/src/moc_ViewerWindow.cxx.o
  [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/data_viewer.dir/src/moc_ShapeAverageThread.cxx.o
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/data_viewer
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/data_viewer] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/data_viewer.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/allenh1/filter_ws/src/data_viewer/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package data_viewer written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/allenh1/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130530-100530/data_viewer/build_output.log
[rosmake-7] Finished <<< data_viewer [FAIL] [ 13.14 seconds ]                  
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package data_viewer. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                           
[ rosmake ] Built 39 packages with 1 failures.                                 
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                        
[ rosmake ] /home/allenh1/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130530-100530
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63938/libpython2.7-build-error,-groovy/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok. Fixed it.

Do this:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1 /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

Note: I am running Ubuntu 13.04. This might not be an issue on previous version of Ubuntu. This fix did work, and the program runs. I am using Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1